# How do I launch the app from within `quickly test` for gui testing?

Tags: application-development, gui, quickly, testing

I'm trying to use [ldtp](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki) to test my quickly app.

`ldtp.launchapp('bin/myapp')` doesn't work because myapp requires whatever voodoo quickly sets up in order to actually launch the app.

How can I get `ldtp.launchapp` to work properly? (Maybe the right question is: What is the voodoo that quickly sets up in order to run the app? Does quickly expose this API so that I can call it from my test?)

Comment: Actually, one major downfall to the `ldtp.launchapp` approach is that `nosetests --with-coverage` doesn't work since the app is launched as a separate process. It would probably be best to do a `MyappWindow().show()`(-ish) directly from within the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes me feel dirty, but it seems to be a viable workaround:

```
class TestMyappClose(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_close(self):
        launchapp('/usr/bin/quickly', ['run'])
        exists = waittillguiexist('*myapp', guiTimeOut=5)
        assert(exists == 1)

        selectmenuitem ('*myapp', 'mnuFile;mnuClose')
        waittillguinotexist('*myapp')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created it using Quickly (the app), "quickly run" (after cd'ing into the folder) will almost always work. If you created it from scratch, then it might not work.

Comment: I think you've missed the point. I'm looking for a way to launch the app *from within a test script* that's invoked by `quickly test` (or `nosetests`). See my answer and my comment below the question -- I'm doing what you suggest from within the test script, but it's not ideal.